# LaTeX elsarticle \cline for array mode

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, arrays

I am making a matrix like this one:

```
    \documentclass[preprint,11pt,3p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath,epsfig,amsfonts,amssymb,subfig}
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathdots}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\nonumber
    F=\left( \begin{array}{c|ccccc|ccccc}
    1&1&\multicolumn{8}{c}{\ldots} & 1\\
    \hline
    1 & \alpha & \alpha^2 & \ldots & \alpha^{m-1} & \alpha^m & \alpha^{-m} & \alpha^{-m+1} & \ldots & \alpha^{-2} & \alpha^{-1} \\
    \multirow{6}{*}{$\vdots$} & \alpha^2 & \alpha^4 & \ldots & \alpha^{-3} & \alpha^{-1} & \alpha & \alpha^3 & \ldots & \alpha^{-4} & \alpha^{-2}\\
    {} & \vdots & \vdots &   & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots\\
    {} & \alpha^m & \alpha^{-1} & \ldots & \alpha^{m(m-1)} & \alpha^{m^2} & \alpha^{-m^2} & \alpha^{-m(m-1)} & \ldots & \alpha & \alpha^{-m}\\
    {} & \multicolumn{10}{c}{\hrulefill}\\
    {} & \alpha^{-m} & \alpha^{-1} & \ldots & \alpha^{m^2-1} & \alpha^{-m^2} & \alpha^{m^2} & \alpha^{-m^2+1} & \ldots & \alpha^{-1} & \alpha^{-m}\\
    {} & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots\\
    1 & \alpha^{-1} & \alpha^{-2} & \ldots & \alpha^{-m+1} & \alpha^{-m} & \alpha^m & \alpha^{m-1} & \ldots & \alpha^2 & \alpha\\
    \end{array} \right)
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but I want the line that I make by `\hrulefill` not to interrupt the vertical line.

`\hline` is only recognized on the full width and cannot be limited to some columns and `\cline` is not recognized as a command in the `array` environment, at least within the packages I use (I am working in `elsarticle`)

I would like to avoid `tabular` because I would have to change all `$` signs. Am I missing some packages? Is there an `\hline`-type thing that can be placed between the `&`'s?

I would very much appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: A quick hint: If you indent lines of code by four spaces -- most easily accomplished by highlighting the lines in question and clicking on the `{}` "button" in the row above the edit window -- they will automatically be formatted as code by the site's software rather than be interpreted as running text.

Comment: Thank you Mico and Christian. Looking whether there is any quick way of re-editing my message, if not I'll take your advice for next time...

Answer (score 4):

I don't follow your comment about `\cline` not being available in the `elsarticle` document class with the packages you load. I experience no problems using `\cline{2-11}` (instead of `{} & \multicolumn{10}{c}{\hrulefill}`) to get a horizontal line that doesn't break up the vertical line between columns 6 and 7.

Given the structure of the matrix, I would left-align rather than center-set the material in all columns but the first. I further suggest you insert a "top strut" in the rows that follow the `\hline` and `\cline` rules. (A typographic strut is an object that has height (or depth) but no width and is thus invisible.) By inserting a suitably-sized "top strut", the math material in the superscript positions doesn't tangle with the horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,11pt,3p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,epsfig,subfig}
\usepackage{mathdots,multirow,relsize}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%% (from code by Claudio Beccari in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993)
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}}   % "top" strut
\begin{document}
\[
F=\left( \begin{array}{c|lllll|lllll}
1&1&\multicolumn{8}{c}{\ldots} & 1\\
\hline
1 & \alpha & \alpha^2 & \ldots & \alpha^{m-1} & \alpha^m & \alpha^{-m} & \alpha^{-m+1} & \ldots & \alpha^{-2} & \alpha^{-1\Tstrut} \\
\multirow{6}{*}{$\vdots$} & \alpha^2 & \alpha^4 & \ldots & \alpha^{-3} & \alpha^{-1} & \alpha & \alpha^3 & \ldots & \alpha^{-4} & \alpha^{-2}\\
{} & \vdots & \vdots &   & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots\\
{} & \alpha^m & \alpha^{-1} & \ldots & \alpha^{m(m-1)} & \alpha^{m^2} & \alpha^{-m^2} & \alpha^{-m(m-1)} & \ldots & \alpha & \alpha^{-m}\\
\cline{2-11}
{} & \alpha^{-m} & \alpha^{-1} & \ldots & \alpha^{m^2-1} & \alpha^{-m^2} & \alpha^{m^2} & \alpha^{-m^2+1} & \ldots & \alpha^{-1} & \alpha^{-m\Tstrut}\\
{} & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots\\
1 & \alpha^{-1} & \alpha^{-2} & \ldots & \alpha^{-m+1} & \alpha^{-m} & \alpha^m & \alpha^{m-1} & \ldots & \alpha^2 & \alpha\\
\end{array} \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My mistake was I was trying to write \cline inside the &'s like

    1 & \cline{2-11}

Now, I still have a problem: unlike in your picture, in mine the first row below the horizontal line has the exponents overlapped with it

This may be because of the struts that my latex does not recognize. Looking up for the right packages...

Comment: @MarcusBarãoCamarão - Did you insert the definition of the `\Tstrut` ("top strut") macro in the preamble and then insert `\Tstrut` directives in some of the superscript terms in the rows below `\hline` and `\cline{2-11}`? (In the example above, the `\Tstrut`s are inserted in the right-hand-most cell; you can, of course, insert them anywhere you want. One instruction per row suffices, naturally.)

Comment: No, Mico, actually I don't know how to make such a definition

Comment: @MarcusBarãoCamarão - Did you see the line `\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}}` in the preamble of the code above?

Comment: Ha! Excuse me, I realized now you have made it for me. Thanks a lot, Mico! It works. You saved quite some time of my life!